# got blank output in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i have tried some complicated type of code in the javascript..Butit gives me a blank page..The code which i have tried is

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566
};

var b = function() {
    return null;
}

person.b({
    name: "yipee",
    age: "20"
});

var somebody = new person();

console.log(somebody.person.b().name);
```

The result i need is yipee ..But i get a blank page instead of that ..Please help me if am doing anything wrong on this code ...Hope you guys can help me out

Comment: You have to press f12 (depending on the browser) to see the console.  It won't write to the page.

Comment: There's nothing there that puts anything on a page.

Comment: did you see anything wrong there on my code ??

Comment: `somebody` is a `person` object.  It doesn't have a `person` property.  `b` is a function.  It's in no way attached to `person` (or `somebody`).  Neither `somebody.person.b` nor `somebody.person` exist.  P.S. `person.b` doesn't exist either, so `person.b({...});` does nothing.  `console.log` prints to the console, not the screen.  Check your browser's console for your output as well as all these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a js error, and that's probably the reason for the blank page.

you are trying to call the function 'b' on the object 'person' which doesn't exsit.

```
console.log(somebody.person.b().name);
```

'b' always returns null, this line will never work

You need something like:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName : "Doe",
    id       : 5566,
    b : function(/* parameters */)
    {
        // do something
        // return something
    }

};
```

Also:

```
var somebody = new person();
```

'person' is not a function, so you can't call 'new' on it.

Comment: so  if b was an object can i try out like person.b({ name: "yipee", age: "20" }); ???

Comment: i have declaired var person ={name: "rm"} var b = function() { return {age: 20} } ..but when i called person.b({ property: 1}) ...i got type error ???

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `Person` function to act as a constructor to initialize a `new` instance and attaching `b` to its prototype so that it can be called as a method.

It's unclear what you want the code to do, but here's something that defines `Person`, creates one from a data bundle, and calls `b` to get the full name.

```
function Person(fields) {
  this.firstName = String(fields.firstName);
  this.lastName = String(fields.lastName);
  this.id = Number(fields.id);
  this.age = Number(fields.age);
}
Person.prototype.b = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
};

var sombody = new Person({
  firstName: "yipee",
  age: "20"
});

console.log(somebody.b());
```

Also see ["Falsehoods programmers believe about names"](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) for why first/last is a poor way to represent names.

Comment: so if b was an object can i try out like  person.b({
    name: "yipee",
    age: "20"
}); ???

Comment: @user3583735, as written `b` takes no arguments so it's not going to do anything with `{ name: ... }`.

Answer (score -1):

use prototype to add

```
person.prototype.b({
name: "yipee",
age: "20"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems as though you are attempting to make `b` a method on your `person` object, but assuming that all you want to do is store another object in `b` your best bet is simply to define it as a property of `person`:

```
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  id       : 5566
};

// Note this function 'b' is completely unrelated to the person
// object that you have defined
var b = function() { return null; };

person.b = {
  name: "yipee",
  age: "20"
};

// I've commented out your attempt to instantiate a new person object 
// because you cannot call `new` on a JS object as you have done. Notice
// how you are calling person with a set of parens, indicating that you
// wish to treat it as a function. Since person is a generic object, not
// a function object, this call to new will not return anything useful

// var somebody = new person();

console.log(person.b.name);
=> "yipee"
```

Alternatively, if you wish for `person.b` to be method call, you can define it like this:

```
person.b = function() {
  return {
    name: "yipee",
    age: "20"
  }
};

person.b().name;
=> "yipee"
```